# Is there a way to disable the inactivity screen lock?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-a8-2018, android-9

And I don't mean the Screen Timeout or the actual phone lock.

I have a Samsung Galaxy A8 running Android 9, and since I found out it hasn't been updated since 2018, AKA before OneUI, I decided to do it.

But since that update, when I don't touch it for a bit, LESS than the ten minutes I set the screen timeout to be, the phone screen get dimmer and lock itself with a 'drag to unlock' message.

It is annoying as I am using a third party program to help me grind in a mobile game, and what it feels like every five minutes I need to unlock the phone screen so that it can keep working. The screenlock must be new because it didn't happen before I updated it.
I tried to see how to turn that off, but all I find is the Screen Timeout and the phone's actual lock, same for google searches. I can't find ANYTHING on this screen lock.

Hell, even the 'Don't go to sleep while plugged it' dev setting doesn't stop it.

Edit : Added a picture to show what I am talking about.
[image: The screen lock that I want to completely disable.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that cause this screen to appear is Game Booster.
I turned it off and I am on my way to uninstall it forever.

Here's the [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidGaming/comments/t2j63f/please_someone_tell_me_how_to_disable_game/) to a reddit post related to how to turn this thing off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).